# evaluate $\int_\frac{-\pi}{4}^\frac{\pi}{4} (\cos t+\sqrt{1+t^2} \sin^3t \cos^3t) \mathrm{d}t$

Tags: integration

How to evaluate $\int_\frac{-\pi}{4}^\frac{\pi}{4} (\cos t+\sqrt{1+t^2} \sin^3t \cos^3t) \mathrm{d}t$ ? I have no clues where to start..Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**:

$$\int_{-\pi/4}^{-\pi/4} (\cos t+\sqrt{1+t^2} \sin^3t \cos^3t) \mathrm{d}t$$

$$ = \int_{-\pi/4}^{+\pi/4} \cos t\;\mathrm{d}t + \int_{-\pi/4}^{+\pi/4}\sqrt{1+t^2} \sin^3t \cos^3t\; \mathrm{d}t$$

The second integral dies out. (why?)

use $$\int_{a}^{b} (f(x))\mathrm{d}x$$
$$ = \int_{a}^{b} (f(a+b-x))\mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: Thanks! I saw it was extremely complicated to evaluate by hand. So I thought it must be something stupid! Stupid it was :D

Comment: @user1500178, do you see why the second integral dies?

Comment: Yes. The integrand of the second part is an odd function. It was stupid..Thanks a lot for pointing it out.

Comment: @ParthThakkar: Iwas about to give the same hint.