# How to solve $\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}\left(\cos{x}-\sqrt{1+x^2}\sin^2{x}\cos^2{x} \right)dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have the following definite integral

$$\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}\left(\cos{x}-\sqrt{1+x^2}\sin^2{x}\cos^2{x} \right)dx$$ and five options:

a) $0$

b) $\sqrt2$

c) $\sqrt 2 -1$

d) $\frac{\sqrt 2-1}{2}$

e) $\sqrt 2-\frac{1}{4}$

I tried to solve the integral, but I'm affraid I have lost a lot of practice and haven't succeeded. I have also tried to deduce its solution using other arguments. For example, since the integral of the cosine is already $\sqrt2$, I discard the option b), as the second summand of the integrand is even and positive for any $x$. However, I haven't been able to discard other options using similar arguments.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2341731/gre-sample-math-practice-book-problem-21-calculus?noredirect=1 , https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/524194/evaluate-int-pi-4-pi-4-cost-sqrt1t2-cost3-sin-t3dt

Comment: A numerical integration shows that none of the choices gives the right value; perhaps there is a typo. If it should be $\cos^3$ and $\sin^3$ instead of $\cos^2$ and $\sin^2$, then clearly the answer is $\sqrt 2$, as @LightYagami is suggesting.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1359037/how-to-integrate-int-pi-4-pi-4-cost-sqrt1-t2-cos3t-sin3 , https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4089218/how-to-solve-int-pi-4-pi-4-left-cosx-sqrt1x2-sin2x-cos2x , ,  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3220369/definite-integral-containing-2-trig-functions-and-a-square-root-function?noredirect=1 , https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/499308/evaluate-int-frac-pi4-frac-pi4-cos-t-sqrt1t2-sin3t-cos3t , https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/499308/evaluate-int-frac-pi4-frac-pi4-cos-t-sqrt1t2-sin3t-cos3t

Comment: I am really surprised by the number of duplicates this question has!

Comment: Non of them is the integral I wrote.

Comment: Yeah, as pointed out by @Théophile most probably it is a typo. It should be cube instead of square.

Comment: What a tasteless typo then ... Thanks guys! Anyway, any clue if the integral with the square can be solved or are there any criteria to choose between those options?

Comment: No, the right answer is 0.226051924403. So, it clearly shows question has a typo.

Comment: WolframAlpha can numerically integrate the definite integral, but it just [gives up](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sqrt%281%2Bx%5E2%29*sin%28x%29%5E2*cos%28x%29%5E2) on the indefinite case... so in short, you had the right idea, but it's an impossible question.