# Is this problem solvable? For real-valued $g(x,y)$ and analytic $f(z)=e^x\sin y+i g(x,y)$, where $z=x+iy$, evaluate $g(3,2)-g(1,2)$

Tags: complex-analysis

On an entrance exam where there is already a [headache-giving typo](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4089218/how-to-solve-int-pi-4-pi-4-left-cosx-sqrt1x2-sin2x-cos2x), I encountered the following problem, which I suspect is also wrong:

> Let $g$ be a real and differentiable function of two variables, and let $f$ be a complex variable function, given by
> $$f(z)=e^x\sin(y)+ig(x,y),$$
>
> where $z=x+iy$. If $f$ is analytic in the complex plane, what is the value of $g(3,2)-g(1,2)$?
>
> a) $e^2$
>
> b) $e^2\big(\sin(3)-\sin(1)\big)$
>
> c) $e^2\big(\cos(3)-\cos(1)\big)$
>
> d) $e-e^3\sin(2)$
>
> e) $(e-e^3)\cos(2)$

I believe something is missing, can someone tell me if this problem is solvable?

Comment: For some reason I can't add the tag `holomorphic-functions`

Comment: @DietrichBurde: $f$ is known to be analytical.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch: neither can I !

Comment: @YvesDaoust That's curious 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint.** By the fundamental Theorem of calculus,

$$g(3,2)-g(1,2) =\int_1^3\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x, 2)\,\mathrm dx.$$

Now use the [Cauchy–Riemann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations) to compute $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$.

Answer (score 2):

We recognize the real part of $-ie^z$, hence

$$\Im(-ie^{3+i2}+ie^{1+i2})=-(e^3-e)\cos 2.$$

(For a more formal solution, integration of the Cauchy-Riemann equations will give $f(z)=-ie^z+c$.)